# PuTTY not running properly (Windows 8)

Tags: windows-8, ssh, putty

I'm trying to run PuTTY on my Windows 8 computer. I downloaded the program onto my desktop, but when I run it, no window pops up and nothing immediately visible happens. I check the task manager though, and it says that it's running as a background process.

[image]

and then,

[image]

(I know both of those prompts in the images are from Windows XP, but I've runn PuTTY on Windows 7 and it usually shows the same prompts). Does anyone know why these windows aren't appearing when I attempt to run it?

Comment: I have Windows 8.1 64 bit and have no problems with Putty running. I remember when upgrading from Windows 7 to Windows 8 I got a massage that putty is not compatible with Windows 8, but I upgraded without uninstalling it and everything seems to work. But I never use Putty instead download WinSCP. There is also a Metro Putty on the Windows Store if you insist on Putty. Also try this: right click on Putty go to properties and on the compatibility tab try to run it in Windows 7 mode. Let me know if it works.

Comment: @Devid Hey, thanks for the info. I tried doing Windows 7 mode, and it didn't work. For good measure I even tried Windows XP mode, but I got the same result. I'll try WinSCP, but I'm still interested to know if there's any way to get PuTTY to work.

Comment: Which Putty version do you have ? My is 0.63 ? Have you tried uninstalling and then installing Putty from the official website ? Additionally your antivirus might be blocking the program or the Firewall or some other third party program. Here the website: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/

Comment: Also just now I checked on my Task Manager in Windows 8.1, Putty is running on Windows Vista OS. So right click on Putty and in the compatibility mode choose Vista and try if it works.

Comment: @Devid Still not working. I even tried doing the two Vista service packs. My version is the same: 0.63. More specifically, it says 0.63.10184.0. I'll try installing it from the third party site...

Comment: I do use putty 0.63.0.0 on Windows 8.1 64 bit, no compatibility mode and not the mentioned problem.

Comment: Maybe Putty will run on the command line, for that you will need to add it to the system variable. Maybe just the GUI does not work. At the end try out WinSCP.

Comment: I also have 0.63 on 8.1 and it runs just fine.

Comment: @Vmai Ok, now I'm at a loss for words. Whenever I try to run WinSCP setup it does the exact same thing as when I try to run puTTY: nothing pops up, it still shows up as an active process in task manager. Other programs seem to run just fine, even programs that I downloaded from the web.

Comment: Try FireSSH and see if it works, if it doesn't then I think it might be faulty installation of the windows. Because I ran putty on my computer with windows 8.1 (AMD64).

Comment: @Ataraxia can you create another account and try to see if WinSCP works from that account. Have you tried running the programs with Admin Privileges ? In Windows Explorer address bar put this sftp://username@example.com is something happening ? Is Remote Desktop Connection working on your PC ? It seems as if some other program is blocking Putty and WinSCP. Have you tried to add Putty to your Path system variable and than run Putty from command line, because maybe the UI is not working, but the program is working fine.

Comment: @Ataraxia This is most likely caused by admin priviledges. Does the UAC prompt appear? If you've installed windows without entering a password, it could explain this behaviour.

Comment: @AlexanderCreed The UAC doesn't appear either, but even running it as administrator doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Ataraxia What about your user account? Do you have a password set on it?

Comment: @AlexanderCeed Yes, my user account has a password set. It's not an administrator account, but I do know the password to the administrator account.

Comment: Do you see putty in Task Manager / Applications? If yes, try right-click and Bring to Front.

Comment: @Ataraxia have you tried the above suggestions ? Is Putty working from other account on your PC ?

Comment: @Harrymc In task manager, it doesn't show up in the applications list. It only shows up as a background process, so the "bring to front" option doesn't show up.

Comment: @Devid I tried from the administrator account, and got the same result. Running PuTTY shows no window, but it still shows up as a background process in Task Manager.

Comment: It must be waiting for something. If you have an antivirus turn it off. Try also to trace what it does via [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx).

Comment: Try to download and run a Portable Putty version , also you can try to run it in Compatibility mode.

Comment: @harrymc I downloaded process monitor and can't run it either. It's doing the same thing.

Comment: @Scorpion99 I tried running it in compatibility mode, for Windows 7, Windows Vista, and Windows XP. Still the same thing.

Comment: Weird, very weird. See if this is happening when booting in Safe Mode with Networking. If yes, run [sfc /scannow](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/3047-sfc-scannow-command-run-windows-8-a.html).

Comment: @Ataraxia it seems as if some important components/files of Windows were deleted or are corrupted (maybe you caught a virus), because many programs don't work as they should on your PC (not just Putty and WinSCP). Run Windows in Safe Mode, if it behaves the same then put the Windows repair disk and repair your OS. If it does not help the best thing is to refresh or/and re-install your OS. If you have a recovery point than restore your PC to an earlier point in time. But I think at the end the best is to re-install your OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to try these:

- Try to run Putty in compatibility mode. Right click on Putty, go to properties and click on the compatibility tab and try to run Putty in Vista or Windows 7 Mode.
- Update or download the latest version of Putty from [**here**](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) (beta 0.63)
- Check if your antivirus/firewall or some other program is blocking Putty.
- Maybe the UI is not showing up but Putty is working fine. Try and add Putty to your [**System Environment Variable Path**](http://www.howtogeek.com/118594/how-to-edit-your-system-path-for-easy-command-line-access/) in Windows and then run the program from the [**command line**](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.63/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline).
- Create another account and try to see if Putty/WinSCP works
  from that account. Don't forget to run Putty with Admin Privileges.
- Try to run Putty in [**Safe Mode**](http://www.howtogeek.com/107511/how-to-boot-into-safe-mode-on-windows-8-the-easy-way/) with Networking.
- Try Windows repair disk and repair your OS. Maybe some files are damaged.

Putty should run in Windows 8.1 without problems. But I see from the comments that you have problems also with WinSCP and some other programs like Remote Desktop Connection and UAC which do run in the background but the UI doesn't show up. It might be that some important components/files of Windows were deleted or are corrupted (maybe you caught a virus), because many programs don't work as they should on your PC (not just Putty and WinSCP). If you tried all the above suggestions I would than do the following:

- If you have a recovery point than restore your PC to an earlier point in time. Otherwise [**refresh or/and re-install**](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/restore-refresh-reset-pc) your Windows 8 OS, which I think at is the best option.

Comment: Running from the command line worked, oddly enough. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem on my system. Using the same version I have been using for months, the Putty window actually pops up and captures mouse and keyboard events but is totally invisible.

I tried Right-Clicking and Moving the window but it didn't show anything except the cursor was on the Window header. Since I usually run with 2 monitors, I tried disconnecting the external monitor and when I reconnected the Putty windows would get flashed up during the screen resets. I tried rebooting but had the same problem.

Remember there has been no change in my system except some Windows Updates last night so the Putty version is not the problem.

Eventually I switched the Display Graphic Properties to 16-bit and it worked but when I ran it again in 32-bit it was invisible again.

**Final solution:** I found that by changing the compatibility settings (Right-Click on the Executeable File Icon and click on Properties. Then in the Compatibility) to Disable desktop composition. And so far so good. Display back to 32 colours.

**BTW:** For those saying to use WinSCP, it is not a complete replacement for Putty since it does not do Serial connections, not even USB to serial like what you need with say Cisco routers and switches, Arduinos or FTDI connected devices.

Answer (score -1):

give a try to a 64 bit statically linked version of putty that works on 8

http://vercot.com/~eputty/default.html

Comment: The essential parts of the answer have been included in my answer.
Unfortunately if a dynamically linked version of PuTTY is the problem in win 8, only a link to a "statically" linked version of it is the solution; and that AFAIK implies posting a link.